# Determining the number of frames in an animation in an FBX file (ASCII)

Tags: animation, fbx

I'm really confused about the actual number of animation frames in an FBX file.
Autodesk FBX review tells me 24, Unity tells me 30, and I think it should be 60.

Therefore I have opened the ASCII version of that FBX file with Notepad++.

I was expecting something like "Keyframes: 60" or similar, but I haven't found such a description within the file.

How could I determine the actual number of frames in that FBX file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complicated. FBX has a clip time and keyframe time per animation stack. These are encoded in FBX time units (you can look that up in FBX documentation). You can use that to calculate clip time and keyframe time in seconds. The difference between clip time and keyframe time is that keyframe time is the length of the longest animation curve in the stack while clip time is just the length of the clip which can by arbitrarily long. Anyway, when you have the lengths in seconds you can multiply that by the frame rate of your animation to get the number of frames. So, for example, if the keyframe length is 1.5 and frame rate is 30, then there should be 45 frames in you longest animation curve. I hope this makes sense.